# Visual Studio 2008 not Aligning Stack Variables?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, opencv, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to read an avi file in OpenCV 2.1, VS2008 standard for 2 days now with no luck. I constantly get this message in the program console:

> Compiler did not align stack variables. Libavcodec has been miscompiled
>   and may be very slow or crash. This is not a bug in libavcodec,
>   but in the compiler. You may try recompiling using gcc >= 4.2.
>   Do not report crashes to FFmpeg developers.

..and the framerate all I get is a 0.5fps playback. I tried with various AVI and MPEG files, still with the same results. Also, the included examples using the webcam are extremely slow. I did not have such problems when using OpenCV 1.1

Things I already tried to resolve this issue:

- Re-compiled the whole library
- Updated the library from SVN and re-compiled
- Tried various version of libavcodec.a file

The code I'm using to read the file is looks like this:

```
CvCapture* input_video = cvCreateFileCapture("c:\\data\test.avi");
// ...
while (true) {
    // ...
    frame = cvQueryFrame( input_video );
    cvShowImage("test", frame); 
    // ...
}
```

Can anyone help me? This is driving me nuts :(

Comment: Please find out the compiler options being used to compile the code in question, and post them here.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should also check cvCaptureFromAVI() to replace cvCreateFileCapture(). Maybe it's a good idea.

But I would most certainly recompile the library. Try adding this option in configure: 
**--enable-force-stack-realign** or **--enable-memalign-hack**

These guys seem to have solved it:
http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=568

If nothing works, why not try the pre-compiled binaries for Windows?
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.1/

Anyway, your question is software specific. I strongly suggest you look for answers in appropriated mailing lists and OpenCV related forums.

Comment: The precompiled binaries are normally built with mingw, I see this problem when linking ming/vs built codecs.

Comment: Binaries compiled with MingW are as good as any other. What happened when you recompiled the sources using the flags I mentioned above? Let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I dedided to use the 1.1 version instead of 2.0, because it works for me and has the features I need and I don't want to put any more time in this problem. Cheers